# MediaCodec decoding h264 wrong on one device

Tags: android, video, h.264, android-mediacodec

I'm trying to decode h.264 stream using Android's MediaCodec interface. Everything is working just fine on my test devices, but on one customer device that I dont' have access to (Samsung Tab S) there are strange issues.

When I decode the stream I don't send any SPS/PPS NALs or an initial frame. I just start pushing the data from the live stream, chopped into blocks ending with a 0x09 NAL and the decoder will synchronize itself nicely without problems quite quickly.

The issue with at least this one device is that when I get a BufferInfo from the decoder it will claim it decoded 1413120 bytes of data, but the buffer size is only 1382400! So of course if I even try to get that much data out of the buffer it will crash.

The video is 1280x720 and is decoded into NV12, so the buffer size is just fine. The reported decoded output size isn't. If I force the size as 1382400 and convert the NV12 into RGB I get almost correct picture. The first 32 lines have a strong green color and the blue channel is shifted by quite a lot. This means that the UV block is decoded partially wrong on this device.

Has anyone run into this kind of an issue before? I have recorded the raw h264 stream from that specific device and it plays just fine with no green blocks or color shifts.

Should I really set up SPS/PPS and an initial frame before starting the streaming? The stream seems to contain everything needed since the decoder realizes the resolution to be correct, sets up buffers and decodes on every other device I've tested except this one. So I'm just wondering if Samsung has something special going on.

Another application decoding the same stream shows it without issues, but as far as I know they use ffmpeg internally, not MediaCodec. I would rather use built-in system codecs if possible.

Here is an example of the result. Don't have an image of just the stream, do note that the frame is rotated. The Y component in the green area is just fine and on the white block on the right you can clearly see the blue shift.

[image]

Edit: Even if I start the decoder with the SPS/PPS blocks in csd-0 the color problems persist. So it isn't due to that.

Also managed to test the exact stream with another device. No green bar, no color shifts. So it's a problem with the codec in that particular device/model.

Comment: Try setting sps/pps as we cannot expect the same behavior on all the devices. Set it and check, it might help.

Comment: Hmm, so to clarify `MediaCodec.BufferInfo.size` is 1413120 but the capacity of the `ByteBuffer` is only 1382400? What does the output `MediaFormat` contain?

Comment: @mstorsjo Yes, the `ByteBuffer` is sized correctly at 1382400, but the `MediaCodec.BufferInfo.size` says 1413120, which is 16 lines of data more than it should be. Output `MediaFormat` has width 1280 and height 720 as it should, haven't checked any other fields.

Comment: Ok, that's strange. The size being larger than necessary is legal in itself, although it may hint that something is wrong.

Comment: Since Android 4.3, the decoders (at least the ones that are picked by default) need to behave correctly, which is enforced via a CTS test. As far as I understood from a quick search, this device is new enough that it runs such an android version. You could try to doublecheck against what the CTS test does: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/jb-mr2-release/tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts/EncodeDecodeTest.java#962 Is there some subtle difference between your code and this, or is it something that the CTS test doesn't check? (It does test decoding 720p in general.)

Comment: Or is this perhaps a case that the CTS test is too loose in what it checks? I.e., the decoder behaves the same as in your code, but the decoder output isn't broken enough to be noticed by the test?

Comment: @mstorsjo It runs 4.4, so I guess it should have been tested. That test seems to do internal testing, so it just tests that what it encodes also decodes, as far as I can see. So it's far from a proper test since a device could just write the input data to output in both encode and decode and be deemed as working. If they had some 3rd party h.264 streams they test against it might mean something. And especially live streams are very different from standalone streams.

Comment: Yes, this particular test only checks that what it encodes also can be decoded, but there are a bunch of other tests as well including decoding streams from a file. (Although, I'm not sure if those tests actually check the output pixels quite as thoroughly as this test does.) With regard to this kind of decoding issue, I have never seen any difference between live streams and standalone files either - the issue would be just as much the same if you'd write the bitstream down into a standalone file and play that.

Comment: What I would suggest here, would be to try to compile the CTS test code I pointed to, and see if it behaves any differently from your code. If it behaves differently, you have a good starting point to try to look for the root cause of the difference; if not, the CTS test should be improved to actually find the issue. (I do have some patches for that, that I haven't submitted since I haven't found an actual buggy device that they'd expose.)

Comment: @mstorsjo The issue is that I don't have access to that device, otherwise this would be a bit simpler to test and adjust. Now I have to handle things second or third hand :/ Also live stream is a bit different since it doesn't have everything nicely in the beginning always and I'm not sure how the NALs are split when reading data from files on the tests. Probably not with manual code. Though I wouldn't think me sending multiple NALs in one input buffer would be a problem, I've noticed that *not* sending multiple will cause the decoder to not decode properly.

Comment: @KarthikKumar I will try to get the proper SPS/PPS and see if it helps. There is just also the issue that the streams aren't always identical, so I'm not sure if those values are the same, but I can most likely handle that separately if this helps.

Comment: Yes, they're different in how/when you have access to the NALs (and you can e.g. pass SPS/PPS either via `csd-0` only, or `csd-0` and `csd-1` via `MediaFormat`, or as a normal input buffer with the  `CODEC_CONFIG` flag). Also, how to handle multiple NALs if the transport doesn't indicate frame boundaries clearly is of course an issue as well. But in any case I think both of them are quite orthogonal issue to malformed pixel data layout like the issue you're seeing (and which the CTS test tries to handle) - I doubt that something such would be related.

Comment: Not having access to the device indeed makes things harder, sorry I forgot you had that situation. (I also checked that http://developer.samsung.com doesn't have any Galaxy Tab S, only Tab S2, available for remote testing, otherwise that would have been an option.)

Comment: @Sami Kuhmonen please do it. If streams have change in sps/pps, we have to identify change in sps/pps values and notify the same to decoder.

Comment: @KarthikKumar Got a test result with the SPS/PPS set, no difference. The color shift and green bar is still there :/

Comment: Yes, SPS/PPS shouldn't relate to this. If you have any sort of visible decoder output, the decoder has received the SPS/PPS somehow (and changing which way it is passed shouldn't matter much) - without this, it is impossible to get any sensible decoding output at all.

Answer (score 4):

I had similar issues in the past (specifically on Samsung devices) and if I remember correctly it was due to the missing SPS/PPS data. You must feed in the SPS/PPS data if you want consistent results.

Not a direct solution to your issue but a possible workaround is to use an alternative decoder (if present) when running on that particular device.

I'm not sure how you are instantiating your decoder but often people use the mime type like so:

```
decoder = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType("video/avc");
```

The device will then choose the preferred decoder (probably hardware).

You can alternatively instantiate a specific decoder like so:

```
decoder = MediaCodec.createByCodecName("OMX.google.h264.decoder");

// OR

decoder = MediaCodec.createByCodecName("OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc");
```

In my experience, most devices have at least 2 different H264 decoders available and you may find that an alternative decoder on this device performs without faults.

You can list all the available codecs using the following code:

```
static MediaCodecInfo[] getCodecs() {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        MediaCodecList mediaCodecList = new MediaCodecList(MediaCodecList.ALL_CODECS);
        return mediaCodecList.getCodecInfos();
    } else {
        int numCodecs = MediaCodecList.getCodecCount();
        MediaCodecInfo[] mediaCodecInfo = new MediaCodecInfo[numCodecs];

        for (int i = 0; i < numCodecs; i++) {
            MediaCodecInfo codecInfo = MediaCodecList.getCodecInfoAt(i);
            mediaCodecInfo[i] = codecInfo;
        }

        return mediaCodecInfo;
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We faced a similar issue of Out of memory when trying to play on Amazon Fire stick (AFTMM) using h265 decoder at 480p and 1440p layer. The issue was coming for both SDR and HDR playback. While this definitely is a device specific issue, there could be some workarounds like reducing the ref value while encoding and/or reducing CRF as well. This works for us.

Answer (score 0):

In my case video has break frame with noise color on device using chip with chipset from Spreadtrum (now known as Unisoc) codec name **"OMX.sprd.h264.encoder"**.

I fixed by ignore this codec and using google codec **"OMX.google.h264.encoder"** as anwser of **@Dean Wild.**

I hope this will help for anyone facing similar my issue.